# How to subtring to a DayOfWeek var?

Tags: c#, substring, dayofweek

how can I add a substring to the lbl_diasemana label?

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
var diasemana = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
lbl_diasemana.Text = diasemana;
```

Comment: what do you mean add a substring.. ? do you mean how do you use the substring function..?

Comment: receive the first 3 characters instead the complete day

Comment: culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).Substring(1,3)

Comment: there you go, thanks man!

Comment: @DavidP you mean `(0,3)` don't you.. C# is `0` Based

Comment: he probably did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Substring` overload which accepts starting index and amount of characters to cut:

```
lbl_diasemana.Text = diasemana.Substring(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DateTime.Today.ToString(...) method with the appropriate format string and culture like this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
lbl_diasemana.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd", culture);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
var diasemana = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).Substring(0,3);
lbl_diasemana.Text = diasemana;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
lbl_diasemana.Text = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).Substring(0, 3);
```

can be done in 2 lines of code

Comment: You could probably do it one line if you want: lbl_diasemana.Text = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).Substring(0, 3);